# Удаление картинки Yii2 (CostaRico/yii2-images)

Tags: php, yii2

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <?php

            $img = $model->getImages();

        ?>
        <div class="row">

            <?php foreach ($img as $item) :?>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center wrap_portf">
                <img src="<?=$item->getUrl()?>" class="img_slider_view" alt="Image">
                <a href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::to('deletemoreimg') ."?id=". $item->id?>" class="btn_port_del">X</a>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

в контролере пробую что то принимать:

```
public function actionDeletemoreimg($id){

    $portfolio = new Portfolio();

    $img = $portfolio->getImage($id);
    $portfolio->removeImage($img);

    return $this->redirect(["portfolio/view?id=$id"]);
}
```

Помогите удалить загружение картинки по одной что виведени форичем, идея такая чтоб можно било удалять картинки по одной, прочитал что ето делаетса методом removeImage($img) вот ссилка источника:
https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images
Помогите пожайлусто удалить картинку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В view:

```
<?php foreach ($img as $item) :?>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center wrap_portf">
        <img src="<?=$item->getUrl()?>" class="img_slider_view" alt="Image">
        <?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('X', ['/portfolio/deletemoreimg', 'imageId' => $item->id, 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn_port_del']) ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

В контроллере:

```
public function actionDeletemoreimg($id){

    $portfolio = Portfolio::findOne($id);

    $imageId = Yii::$app->request->get('imageId');
    $img = $portfolio->getImage($imageId);
    $portfolio->removeImage($img);

    return $this->redirect(["/portfolio/view", "id" => $id]);
}
```

Ну, как-то так.  И не забудь проверить права пользователя на удаление этой картинки.

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = Products::findOne($id);

$img = $model->getImages();

foreach ($img as $item) {

    if ($item->id == $imgId) $model->removeImage($item);

}
```

1. Вот так у меня сработало, предыдущее не работало.
2. Это в контроллере.